# jquery show all divs with class more inside clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

i like to hide all "c1" inside the clicked class "brick":

```
<div class="brick">
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
</div>

<div class="brick">
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
</div>


 $(document).on("click touchend", ".brick", function(event) {
    $(".c1").hide();
});
```

But if i click on brick all "c1" will be hidden. But i like to hide for example only the "c1" in the first brick because i clicked on the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the element based on the current event scope. Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
$(document).on("click touchend", ".brick", function(event) {
    $(this).find(".c1").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="brick">
    <div class="c1">brick 1 - c1</div>
    <div class="c2">brick 1 - c2</div>
    <div class="c3">brick 1 - c3</div>
    <div class="c1">brick 1 - c1</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="brick">
    <div class="c1">brick 2 - c1</div>
    <div class="c2">brick 2 - c2</div>
    <div class="c3">brick 2 - c3</div>
    <div class="c1">brick 2 - c1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$(this)` to trap the context then
you have lot of solutions, one is to use `children()` for example

```js
$(document).on("click touchend", ".brick", function(event) {
    $(this).children(".c1").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="brick">
<div class="c1">brick 1 - c1</div>
<div class="c2">brick 1 - c2</div>
<div class="c3">brick 1 - c3</div>
<div class="c1">brick 1 - c1</div>
</div>

<hr>



<div class="brick">
<div class="c1">brick 2 - c1</div>
<div class="c2">brick 2 - c2</div>
<div class="c3">brick 2 - c3</div>
<div class="c1">brick 2 - c1</div>
</div>
```